# Cassandra time datatype

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, datastax, cassandra-2.1

Using DataStax 4.8.11 with Cassandra 2.1.17, Ubuntu14.04
I am trying to create a table with **time data type**. The syntax works fine on Cassandra 2.2.8/Win7, but not on DataStax 4.8.11.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE tests WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};

CREATE TABLE testts (
            ID int PRIMARY KEY,
            mdate timestamp,            
            ttime time);
```

I get error :

Invalid request: code=2200 [Invalid Query] message=Unknown type tests.time]

Thanks

Comment: include your query please

Answer (score 2):

The `time` data type was [introduced in protocol version 4](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.9/doc/native_protocol_v4.spec#L1167), which requires Cassandra 2.2+ (DataStax Enterprise 5.0+).  Because of this, `time` cannot be used for a column in DataStax 4.8.x / Cassandra 2.1.

Comment: Andy Thanks for clarifying this. I suspected/guessed something like this somehow the API docs didn't have the @since (maybe I missed it). I will try look for alternate solution.